# Modern Warfare 2 doesn't have cheats for the single player campaign?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, cheats

In the original Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare, when you collected enemy intelligence (laptops scattered throughout the single player campaign), you unlocked cheats that could be activated while playing the single player game.

The sequel, Modern Warfare 2, doesn't seem to have such a mechanism.  I've collected all 45 enemy intel laptops, but I don't appear to have gained anything, other than the achievement **Leave No Stone Unturned**.  Is this true?  The only reward for collecting the laptops is an achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a look around and in the game, but all evidence I can find points to it just being an achievement, just like it is in lots of games. Seems like MW1 was just an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, collecting "Enemy Intelligence" is achievement only.